# Dynamically change title and content of Bootstrap 4.x Popover

Tags: bootstrap-4

When using Bootstrap 3.x Popovers I was able to change the Popover title and content while it is visible by changing the options and then re-showing the Popover, like this:

```
var popover = $('#myid').data('bs.popover');

popover.options.title = "My Title";
popover.options.content = "My content";

$("#myid").popover('show');
```

This doesn't work anymore in Bootstrap 4.x.

Is there a similar way to do this in 4.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here: [bootstrap popover change content dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428992/bootstrap-popover-change-content-dynamically)

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()

$('#myid').attr('data-original-title', 'New title');
$('#myid').attr('data-content', 'New content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="myid" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. I didn't see the other question but your answer is more concise so helpful to myself and I'm sure others who come across the same issue. Note to others: if like me you are wanting to change the title and/or content while the popover is already displayed then you must reshow the popover after changing the attributes, eg `$("#myid").popover('show');`.